# How can I get direct video url from YouTube video URL?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, youtube, react-native

I'm going to play YouTube and Vimeo videos using React-Native.
For now I implemented [React-Native-Video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) and it does not support to play YouTube or Vimeo urls while can play direct video urls.
So I just want to get a direct reference to a file (or a stream?) from YouTube Video URL.
    e.g from

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCwL3-hkKrg
```

Is there any good third party services or websites to solve this problem?
No matter what types of code or ways you will use though I'm using React-Native to play YouTube videos currently.

Comment: What do you mean by "direct video url"?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: Url that we can download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get youtube video file reference url from [KeepVid](http://keepvid.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPCwL3-hkKrg) website.

Because I don't think the website supports restful api, I fetched its html content and parsed to get download urls.
I didn't write code here as it is very simple.
I would be glad if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain video urls of YouTube by this code:

```
    // ES6 version
const videoUrls = ytplayer.config.args.adaptive_fmts
  .split(',')
  .map(item => item
    .split('&')
    .reduce((prev, curr) => (curr = curr.split('='),
      Object.assign(prev, {[curr[0]]: decodeURIComponent(curr[1])})
    ), {})
  )
  .reduce((prev, curr) => Object.assign(prev, {
    [curr.quality_label || curr.type]: curr
  }), {});

console.log(videoUrls);

// ES5 version
var videoUrls = ytplayer.config.args.adaptive_fmts
  .split(',')
  .map(function (item) {
    return item
      .split('&')
      .reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        curr = curr.split('=');
        return Object.assign(prev, {[curr[0]]: decodeURIComponent(curr[1])})
      }, {});
  })
  .reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return Object.assign(prev, {
      [curr.quality_label || curr.type]: curr
    });
  }, {});

console.log(videoUrls);
```

Comment: the outputted links do not work. Getting access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand what you want - downloading or playing a video[stream] from URL of Youtube or Vimeo.

The **only possible way** is to use WebView since it's not possible to get the link to the regarding file (*not "direct url"*) of Vimeo nor YouTube for playing (maybe possible for downloading).

If you have to compose customized control, e.g.  with your own SeekBar or buttons, ... then you can implement it by combining with WebView control, right?
I don't expect this will be much trouble to implement.